# Rewriting ret address when leaving a function

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to rewrite ret adress from function foo() to skip first instruction after leaving function foo(). I'm following Smash stack for fun or profit and Hacking by Jon Erickson. Here is simple code where I want to skip "b = 2;" instruction, so in b should be stored value 1.

Compiled in gcc, settings: -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -g

Also I have turned off ASLR.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo() {
    int c = 0;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = (int*) 0x00007fffffffdf38;
    // Second instruction after leaving from foo(). I also tried to skip all instructions before call printf function.
    *ptr = 0x0000000000400577; 
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 1;
    foo();
    b = 2;
    printf("b = %d\n", b);      
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this program is: "b = 2".

How I assumed where is stored RET instruction:

```
(gdb) disass main
...
0x000000000040056b <+20>:   call   0x40052d <foo>
0x0000000000400570 <+25>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x2
0x0000000000400577 <+32>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
0x000000000040057a <+35>:   mov    esi,eax
...
(gdb) break 4       // set breakpoint 1 in function foo before int *ptr;
(gdb) break 7       // set breakpoint 2 in function foo after rewriting RET for checking
(gdb) run
(gdb) x/8x &c       // "x/8x $esp" doesn't work, it says: "Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffdf30", so I'm looking into memory from &c
0x7fffffffdf2c: 0x00000000  0xffffdf50  0x00007fff  0x00400570
0x7fffffffdf3c: 0x00000000  0xffffe030  0x00007fff  0x00000000
// simple math tell me, it should be:
(gdb) x/8xb 0x7fffffffdf38
0x7fffffffdf38: 0x70    0x05    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

This is how I have found the RET address, it is at 0x7fffffffdf38. To this place I'm putting address of next instruction - 0x0000000000400577.
However, computer still didn't skip instruction b = 2, even when RET is successfully rewrited.
I checked it for confirmation if it really replaced the RET address:

```
(gdb) c
(gdb) x/8xb 0x7fffffffdf38
0x7fffffffdf38: 0x77    0x05    0x40    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

So RET address is really rewrited but when program leaves from function foo() it jumps to original address 0x0000000000400570 wich I want to skip...

It should be simple, find where is stored ret adress and then put to this place other adress. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for every answer.

For specifying the questing I'm adding dissasembled functions:

```
Dump of assembler code for function foo:
0x000000000040052d <+0>:    push   rbp
0x000000000040052e <+1>:    mov    rbp,rsp
0x0000000000400531 <+4>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
0x0000000000400538 <+11>:   movabs rax,0x7fffffffdf38
0x0000000000400542 <+21>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rax
0x0000000000400546 <+25>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
0x000000000040054a <+29>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rax],0x400577
0x0000000000400550 <+35>:   mov    eax,0x0
0x0000000000400555 <+40>:   pop    rbp
0x0000000000400556 <+41>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000000400557 <+0>:    push   rbp
0x0000000000400558 <+1>:    mov    rbp,rsp
0x000000000040055b <+4>:    sub    rsp,0x10
0x000000000040055f <+8>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
0x0000000000400566 <+15>:   mov    eax,0x0
0x000000000040056b <+20>:   call   0x40052d <foo>
0x0000000000400570 <+25>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x2
0x0000000000400577 <+32>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
0x000000000040057a <+35>:   mov    esi,eax
0x000000000040057c <+37>:   mov    edi,0x400624
0x0000000000400581 <+42>:   mov    eax,0x0
0x0000000000400586 <+47>:   call   0x400410 <printf@plt>
0x000000000040058b <+52>:   mov    eax,0x0
0x0000000000400590 <+57>:   leave  
0x0000000000400591 <+58>:   ret
```

Comment: It's not 100 percent clear to me what you're doing, but the return instruction is pushed on stack by the call instruction. The location of the RET instruction (your 0x7fffffffdf38 value) seems irrelevant. You should locate the return address in the current stack frame, which was pushed by `call` and modify that.

Comment: I have found (from dbg, break 4 - inside foo) that on 0x7fffffffdf38 is stored 0x0000000000400570 which is next instruction. So 0x7fffffffdf38 is place, where is stored return adress, isn't it?

Comment: Please post the entire disassembly of both `main` and `foo` if you want me to comment further.

Comment: Within `foo` here your return address should be located at `[rbp+8]`.

Comment: Seems right to me, except your question is badly worded because you are trying to change the **return address** and not the **ret instruction**.  I'm not seeing any problem with what you did, though, as long as the stack pointer is the same between runs.  Perhaps a more stable program would use `p = &c + 3;`.

Comment: Is there any way to change [rbp+8] from c source or debugger?
Oh, sorry for question name. But yes, stack pointer is always the same. I have tried to run and look with dbg inside many times.
Also tried p = &c + 3; as you are suggesting. Also replaced value 3 and tried all values from 0 to 80, wanting to put adress to whole stack and still nothing...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When I run this in gdb debugger it works. So the code is written good, question solved. The problem is somewhere else...

Comment: Please edit your question, rather than providing additional informations as an answer.